# How to remove expressvpn daemon?

Tags: linux-mint, openvpn, vpn

I uninstalled ExpressVPN on Linux a long time ago, but I have noticed in syslog that there was still an expressvpn service trying to connect every couple of minutes, which is strange since I uninstalled the program.

```
May 30 15:42:00 COMPUTER-NAME systemd[1]: expressvpn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
May 30 15:42:00 COMPUTER-NAME systemd[1]: expressvpn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 30 15:42:05 COMPUTER-NAME systemd[1]: expressvpn.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
May 30 15:42:05 COMPUTER-NAME systemd[1]: expressvpn.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1761.
May 30 15:42:05 COMPUTER-NAME systemd[25122]: expressvpn.service: Failed to execute command: No such file or directory
May 30 15:42:05 COMPUTER-NAME systemd[25122]: expressvpn.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/sbin/expressvpnd: No such file or directory
```

I have tried to:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f expressvpn disable
```

`sudo update-rc.d -f expressvpn.service disable`

But it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted ExpressVPN who gave me the solution.

1. Uninstall the app: sudo yum remove expressvpn or **sudo apt remove expressvpn**
2. Check for any Expressvpn folder: whereis expressvpn
   If there's an existing "/usr/lib/expressvpn" delete this using: sudo rm -r /usr/lib/expressvpn
3. Check if there's an existing directory/files in usr/lib (if none, proceed with step 4): find /usr/lib/expressvpn
4. Delete expressvpn service: sudo rm /etc/systemd/system/expressvpn.service
5. Reload systemd manager configuration: systemctl daemon-reload